How should I connect a new fan switch to the house wiring?
I have a 3 speed fan with a 4 wire switch. There is no light fixture.  The new switch has pre-installed wires.  Do I connect the switch wire marked L directly to the hot wire?  The other 3 wires are red (1), blue (2), and white (3).  I am not sure where they go - especially the white.  Can you help?
